# I am brand new to Javascript, and am struggling to get a simple form to work. Can I please get some advice?

Tags: javascript, forms, simple-form

My code is below. Trying to create a simple form for an assignment.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Adoption Form</title>
<script>
function getInfo(){

var first = 
document.forms["formInfo"]["first"].value;
var last = 
document.forms["formInfo"]["last"].value;

var applicantInfo = "My first name is " + first + " My last name is " + last ".";

document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = applicantInfo;

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <form id="formInfo" name="formInfo">
        <p>My first name is <input name="first" type="text" id="first" title="first"></p>
        <p> My last name is <input name="last" type="text" id="last" title="last"></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Send Information" onClick="getInfo()"></p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="info">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I press the button in the browser, nothing happens. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are using Script function on top, which is actually a bad idea because you are trying to get the values even before they are loaded. You are trying to access the value of first and last name which is not even loaded. So you have two choices either to put down the script tag at bottom of body tag or you can use window.onload (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).

Comment: @SuhailAkhtar the function doesn't execute unless it's triggered by an input click, the script is perfectly fine under the circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes first it's `onclick` with a small `c` not `onClick`.
Second you are missing a  `+` after `last`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Adoption Form</title>
    <script>
      function getInfo() {
        var first = document.forms["formInfo"]["first"].value;
        var last = document.forms["formInfo"]["last"].value;

        var applicantInfo =
          "My first name is " + first + " My last name is " + last + ".";

        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = applicantInfo;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form id="formInfo" name="formInfo">
        <p>
          My first name is
          <input name="first" type="text" id="first" title="first" />
        </p>
        <p>
          My last name is
          <input name="last" type="text" id="last" title="last" />
        </p>

        <p>
          <input type="button" value="Send Information" onclick="getInfo();" />
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="info"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works,  here is the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8b65omus/2/)

You were simply missing a concatenation operator(+) toward the end of your variable assignment.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Adoption Form</title>
<script>
function getInfo(){

var first = 
document.forms["formInfo"]["first"].value;
var last = 
document.forms["formInfo"]["last"].value;

var applicantInfo = "My first name is " + first + " My last name is " + last + ".";

document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = applicantInfo;

};
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    <form id="formInfo" name="formInfo">
        <p>My first name is <input name="first" type="text" id="first" title="first"></p>
        <p> My last name is <input name="last" type="text" id="last" title="last"></p>

        <p><input type="button" value="Send Information" onClick="getInfo()"></p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="info">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```